# Access outdoor controls from classes - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class

Hi and I'm sorry for askin' dummy questions. I have a class which it has to invalidate my workspace(PictureBox) to perform some motion. But I can't do it because it totally doesn't run.

My class:

```
Public Class clsLayoutObject
    Private tmrAnimation As New Timer

    Public oID As UInteger
    Public oName As String
    Public oGraphic As New List(Of Image)
    Public oMaxFrame As UInteger
    Public oActiveFrame As UInteger
    Public oFrameRate As UInteger = 100
    Public oX As Integer, oY As Integer
    Public oWidth As Integer, oHeight As Integer
    Public oDepth As UInteger
    Public oLocked As Boolean
    Public oVisible As Boolean

    Private tempActiveFrame As UInteger

    Private Sub playAnimation()
        AddHandler tmrAnimation.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf animationPlayback)
        tmrAnimation.Interval = oFrameRate
        tmrAnimation.Start()
        tempActiveFrame = oActiveFrame
    End Sub

    Private Sub animationPlayback()
        --> frmmain.Workspace.Invalidate()
        If oActiveFrame < oMaxFrame Then
            oActiveFrame += 1
        Else
            oActiveFrame = 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub animationPause()
        tmrAnimation.Stop()
        frmmain.Workspace.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub animationStop()
        oActiveFrame = tempActiveFrame
        tmrAnimation.Stop()
        frmmain.Workspace.Invalidate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm not familiar with OO programming too much and I'm still improving. Thanks.

Comment: Don't make us guess how oActiveFrame changes the displayed image in a completely different form.

Comment: No, the displayed image is completely separated. I mean the class itself, doesn't display the image rather it just store the frames and my other function **out of this class** goes through them and it shows them. What am I doing! It's better to put the code.

Comment: In what way does it not run?  Do you get a compile time error or a runtime exception?  What is the error?  Also, given that all methods are `Private`, I'm failing to see how anything in that class runs.  How does the rest of your program interact with this class?

Comment: :) I just wrote the playAnimation function as a `private`. It's a `public` one. No there is no error or warning depend on the correction or something else. It just doesn't run. Imagine it skips that line. I know something is wrong with me but I don't know what is it!